# GObject funtion to change the window title

Tags: c, gtk

Is it possible to change the title of a window using a GObject method?

I have the below lines of code

```
window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"Hello World");
```

What I wish to do is to replace the **gtk_window_set_title** with a method defined in GObject(ie one of its ancestor class) so as to change the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many gettable and settable values in a GObject are provided as *properties*. One of the properties of GtkWindow is `"title"`. You can get properties with `g_object_get()` and set them with `g_object_set()`.

The GObject version of `gtk_window_set_title()` then is

```
g_object_set(window, "title", "New title", NULL);
```

Each class has a Properties section in its documentation showing all the properties for that class. A class also inherits the properties of its superclasses. [Here's the documentation for `g_object_set()`.](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set)

Comment: Thank-you ! So as per the docs I could set everything using this : `g_object_set(window,"title","Hello World","default-width",300,"default-height",100,NULL)`

Comment: I want to point out that using g_object_set() is generally slower than a direct setter function, because the values have to be wrapped and unwrapped using the generic GValue wrapper; also, variadic functions like g_object_set() has gotchas when it comes to reading float values that can cause hard to debug crashes or misbehaviours; finally, you're foregoing compile-time type validation. In short: use the function accessors.